# Prime Faces dialog with modal panel issue

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

When using the `<p:dialog>` tag (in Prime Faces 3.3.1) with the modal attribute set to true I get strange behaviour. The "dark semi-transparent panel" - which stands between the popup and the page - covers the page size from top to bottom correctly, but when I scroll down the page it is cut.

I think the Prime Faces (or jQuery) is retrieving the size of the window instead the size of the page to calculate the dark semi-transparent panel dimensions.

Any ideas?

This is my code:

```
<p:dialog draggable="false" id="dialogAddItems" header="Add item" modal="true" resizable="false" widgetVar="widgetDialogAddItems" width="600" height="200">
    <h:form>
        ...
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem with primefaces 3.4, setting the attribute `appendToBody="true"` of `<p:dialog>` solved the problem. I hope this solves your problem too.

Comment: Also you might want to take a look at this http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=576, This is a bug in primefaces

Comment: appendToBody=true causes some issues with the way the back bean handles requests. This is definitely a bug in primefaces. I hope they fix it soon.

Answer (score 0):

So, I tried `appendToBody="true"` and placing the tag in many different places on the page. Nothing worked. Tried even updating Prime Faces to lastest version. Didn't work either. So, my solution was a workaround, but it's because I have no other ideas:

```
.ui-widget-overlay {
   position: fixed !important;
   top: 0px !important;
}
```

Comment: I tried adding this to my CSS to override the current theme, but no luck. I am still forced to use p:dialog with modal=false. I hope they fix this with the next release.